# Calculate distance matrix in km units

Tags: qgis, distance-matrix, units

I would like to create a distance matrix and have as output the distances expressed as kilometers (km).

Here my current output, which I believe is in degrees and NOT in km:

[image]

My coordinate system (CRS) is `EPSG:27700, OSGB 1936 / British National Grid`, I am working with an Apple computer on QGIS 2.14

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unit of [EPSG:27700, OSGB 1936 / British National Grid](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/osgb-1936-british-national-grid/html/) is meter, which means the distances you got are in meter. You need to divide by 1000 and you will get the distance in km.

Answer (score 1):

Useful will be the following formula:

```
Round((Distance)/1000,0)
```

Assuming that you want to have a full km.

**Distance** - the name of the column produced by the Distance Matrix tool.